# Write statement for a complex format / possibility to write more than once on the same excel line

Tags: excel, fortran

I am presently working on a file to open one by one .txt documents, extract data, to finally fill a .excel document.

Because I did not know how it is possible to write multiple times on the same line of my Excel document after one write statement (because it jumps to the next line), I have created a string of characters which is filled time after time :

```
Data (data_limite(x),x=1,8)/10, 9, 10, 7, 9, 8, 8, 9/

    do file_descr = 1,nombre_fichier,1
            taille_data1 = data_limite(file_descr)
            nvari = taille_data1-7
            write (new_data1,"(A30,A3,A11,A3,F5.1,A3,A7,F4.1,<nvari>(A3))") description,char(9),'T-isotherme',char(9),T_trait,char(9),'d_gamma',taille_Gam,(char(9),i=1,nvari)
            ecriture_descr = ecriture_descr//new_data1
    end do
```

Main issue was I want to adapt `char(9)` amount with the `data_limite` value so I built a write statement with a variable amount of `char(9)`.

At the end of the do-loop, I have a very complex format of `ecriture_descr` which has no periodic format due to the change of the `nvari` value

Now I want to add this to the first line of my .excel :

```
   Open(Unit= 20 ,File='resultats.RES',status='replace')      

    write(20,100) 'param',char(9),char(9),char(9),char(9),char(9),'*',char(9),'nuances',char(9),'*',char(9),ecriture_descr
100  format (a5,5(a3),a,a3,a7,a,a3,???)
```

but I do not know how to write this format. It would have been easier if, at each iteration of the do-loop I could fill the first line of my excel and continue to fill the first line at each new new_data1 value.

EDIT : maybe adding advance='no' in my write statement would help me, I am presently trying to add it

EDIT 2 : it did not work with advance='no' but adding a '$' at the end of my format write statement disable the return of my function. By moving it to my do-loop, I guess I can solve my problem :). I am presently trying to add it

Comment: Note that the `<nvari>` is highly non-standard. It is better to build the character from smaller strings and put the actual value there. Often you can just use an arbitrary large value at the and of the format string.

Comment: Hello Vladimir, ok I just saw this solution on another post and it seemed to work. Because I wanna write characters on a line, using a larger value wouldn't move it to the right on my excel document by adding the wrong amount of char(9) ?

Comment: not that it hurts anything but why `a3` for a single character? Personally i would just use `a` for all the strings, using `trim` as needed around character variables, then your format is just `11a` or even `*(a)`

Comment: seeing edit, the `$` is a non standard (but common) extension.  What compiler are you using that doesn,t support `advance='no'`?

Comment: Adding $ is also non-stabdard, isn't it?

Comment: And when already nitpicking, achar(9) is more correct then char(9).

Comment: you're right, I was just using 3a and a to dissociate char(9) and '*' :)

Comment: aside to all this i prefer `csv` for excel import, give the file a `.csv`. extension and excel will just open it w/o poking through a bunch of dialogs telling it what the delimiter is.  (same code, just use `','` instead of `char(9)` )

Comment: I am using Microsoft Visual Studio as compiler but adding advance='no' into my write statement such like write(20,100,advance='no') did not work for me

Comment: Ok !! You both are very gentle to help me ! I will try to use all the elements u give me to upgrade my code ! Thank you

Comment: *I am using Microsoft Visual Studio as compiler*  Not really you're not. Visual Studio doesn't provide Fortran compilation.  Perhaps you're using Intel Fortran which integrates nicely into Visual Studio.

Comment: Indeed ! Compiling with Intel(R) Visual Fortran Compiler XE 12.1.7.371 [IA-32]...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your line

```
ecriture_descr = ecriture_descr//new_data1
```

Is almost certainly not doing what you expect it to do. I assume that both `ecriture_descr` and `new_data` are of type `CHARACTER(len=<some value>)` -- that is a fixed length string. If you assign anything to such a string, the string is cut to length (if the assigned is too long), or padded with spaces (if the assigned is too short:

```
program strings
    implicit none
    character(len=8) :: h
    h = "Hello"
    print *, "|" // h // "|"  ! Prints "|Hello   |"
    h = "Hello World"
    print *, "|" // h // "|"  ! Prints "|Hello Wo|"
end program strings
```

And this combination will work against you: `ecriture_descr` will already be padded to the max with spaces, so when you append `new_data1` it will be just outside the range of `ecriture_descr`, a bit like this:

```
h = "Hello"         ! h is actually "Hello   "
h = h // "World"    ! equiv to h = "Hello    " // "World"
                    !            = "Hello    World"
                    !               ^^^^^^^^^
                    !      Only this is assigned to h => no change
```

If you want a string aggregator, you need to use the `trim` function which removes all trailing spaces:

```
h = trim(h) // " World"
```

Secondly, if you want to write to a file, but don't want to have a newline, you can add the option `advance='no'` into the write statement:

```
do i = 1, 100
    write(*, '(I4)', advance='no') i
end do
```

This should make your job a lot easier than to create one very long string in memory and then write it all out in one go.

Comment: Hello,
my ecriture_descr is of this type : character(:),allocatable:: ecriture_descr. I thought it would allow me to not assign a limitation on the length of this string of characters.

Because my new_data1 ending is full of char(9), will the trim erase the amount designed char(9) ending my ecriture_descr ?

Thank you for your help

Nicolas

Comment: `trim()` only trims actual blank spaces  ( `char(32)` ), it wont touch tabs.

Comment: I have added some comments about how to write to a file without adding a linebreak.

Comment: chw21, write(20, '(I4,$)') i worked but not with advance='no'. But you are right, this looks like an easier way to do